# dynamic binding

Tags: java, binding

читаю "Философию Java" Эккеля. Как-то к сожалению он сложно описывает некоторые моменты, и один из таких: `Динамическое связывание`.

Я хорошо понимаю на примерах где есть статическое связывание, а где динамическое. Но как именно компилятор узнаёт какой метод вызвать если действует полиморфизм?

Вот как это описал Эккель: "...Присоединение вызова метода к телу метода называеться ***связыванием***  ...Проблема решаеться благодаря ***позднему связыванию***, тоесть связыванию проводимому во время выполнения программы, в зависимости от типа объекта..."

Вопрос: Кто-нибудь может объяснить *простыми словами* как компилятор определяет к какому объекту вызвать метод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простые слова: компилятор это делает с помощью таблицы виртуальных методов.

https://eelcovisser.org/blog/2011/05/08/virtual-method-tables/

Comment: Прочитал.
Надеюсь на собеседовании меня не будут спрашивать за виртуальные таблицы 0_0

Comment: @НазарСтинянский Надо знать, что они существуют, и что они в принципе собой представляют.